# promise parameter from firestore set is undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a new document and then do something inside the promise using the following way :

```
      firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).set({name: "testName"})
      .then(res => {
        console.log("set data correctly with ", res);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('something went wrong '+ err)
      });
```

It indeed went into the `then` promise. However, the `res` is empty!
I got:

> set data correctly with undefined

Comment: Answer on why this happens below. What are you trying to do in the `then()` callback, and what value do you need for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the API documentation for [DocumentReference.set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#set).  The method is defined like this:

```
set(data: DocumentData, options?: SetOptions): Promise<void>
```

Note that the method returns a Promise that contains `void`.  That means set() doesn't yield any objects or data at all.

So, if you use that promise, it will be delivered nothing.  So it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The [`DocumentReference.set()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) returns a `Promise<void>`. So it is expected that there's no value passed to `then().`